# Call command-line function in Perl and get output as String

Tags: perl, postgresql, command-line, plperl

What is the best/easiest way to execute a command line function in Perl, such that I can get the output as a String?

What I'm actually trying to do is call a Java program from within a PL/Perl function in PostgreSQL, and I want the output String, however at the moment it seems to just be returning 0.

Here is a simple piece of code to explain what I am after:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION perl_func()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$    
  return system("java -version");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plperlu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: `system` returns the result code of executing the program. So it's a good thing that it returns 0. That just means you'll have to use backticks per Jack Maney's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backticks.  Quoting from [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> *qx/STRING/
>
> *`STRING`
>
> A string which is (possibly) interpolated and then
>   executed as a system command with /bin/sh or its equivalent. Shell
>   wildcards, pipes, and redirections will be honored. The collected
>   standard output of the command is returned; standard error is
>   unaffected. In scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially
>   multi-line) string, or undef if the command failed. In list context,
>   returns a list of lines (however you've defined lines with $/ or
>   $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR), or an empty list if the command failed.

You can't use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for this, since it just returns the return value of the argument (when run as a shell command).  This should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION perl_func()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
  my $output=`java -version`;
  chomp($output);
  return $output;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plperlu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Note that the output of a backticked command usually includes a trailing newline, so it's often useful to get rid of that via `chomp`.

Comment: Actually, this seems to return an error: `Can't modify quoted execution (``, qx) in chomp at line 1, near "`java -version`)”` And when trying it without the chomp, it just returns an empty cell. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...try the `chomp` separately (as done in the edited code above).