# Trigger-Function arguments PLSH

Tags: postgresql, function, shell, triggers

I created a shell script which take an integer argument to send me a mail.

Now I try to create a trigger on my psql database which send the id of the inserted row which fired the trigger to my shell script using the [plsh extension](https://github.com/petere/plsh).

So I created a function sendMailContact() and a trigger mailContact :

TRIGGER mailContact :

```
CREATE TRIGGER mailcontact
  AFTER INSERT
  ON contact
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sendmailcontact(NEW);
```

FUNCTION sendMailContact :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sendmailcontact()
RETURNS trigger AS '
#!/bin/sh
/home/me/Scripts/sendMailContact.sh NEW.id'
LANGUAGE plsh;
```

But the "NEW.id" seems to doesn't works properly (Here it's part of the code because I was not able to pass it as a variable). According to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35654749/5591761
And from the official README file, the NEW.x has to work but here it doesn't.

I also tried the TG_ARGV[0] which is used to pass argument from trigger to function in standard SQL langage but I don't really know how to use it here. Maybe the plsh extension provide us a new table of argument but I didn't find it.

Finally I tried to pass directly the id to the function and use it with $1 on my function but it doesn't work aswell

How can I pass the id (integer) of the inserted row to my function and use it as an argument for my shell script ?

**----- EDIT : -----**

After I took a look at the answers you provided me, I edited my function like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sendmailcontact()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
/home/pi/Scripts/sendMailContact.sh $2
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh
```

I used $2 because the id is the first column of the INSERT (id is a serial auto incremental but I think it's a part of the INSERT aswell ?)

Then the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER mailcontact
  AFTER INSERT
  ON contact
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sendmailcontact(NEW);
```

It still don't working.

But I noticed that the INSERT doesn't work anymore if the trigger is activated. Nothing is added to my table.

*In case you are asking if the script or the trigger work the answer is yes, before this I wrote the almost same trigger and function with the trigger calling the function when I INSERT in the contact. The function was just sending me a mail without any argument and either the mail and the INSERT were working.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running system command with argument in a PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205594/running-system-command-with-argument-in-a-postgresql-function)

Comment: The linked answer should contain enough information, but: `EXECUTE PROCEDURE sendmailcontact(NEW)` **don't do that**. That will mean you want to use `'NEW'` **as a string** as a constant trigger parameter & plsh will prepend that to its parameters (so `$1` will be the string `NEW`, `$2` is the first column, etc.)

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

you can check the docs about triggers in  plsh

example:

https://github.com/petere/plsh/blob/master/test/sql/trigger.sql

output:

https://github.com/petere/plsh/blob/master/test/expected/trigger.out

maybe you questions is about this code part inside trigger :
...
for arg do
    echo "Arg is '$arg'"
done
...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any variable to the trigger function, just use bash `$0`..`$n` variables (the values are in the same order of the columns definition order).

Here a small complete demo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE demo_table(column1 varchar, column2 varchar);

CREATE FUNCTION demo_trigger_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
#!/bin/sh
# Prints on stderr for demo purposes
>&2 echo "column1=$1"
>&2 echo "column2=$2"
exit 0
$$ LANGUAGE plsh;

CREATE TRIGGER demo_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON demo_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE demo_trigger_fn();

INSERT INTO demo_table(column1, column2) VALUES('value1', 'value2');
```